My kernel always dies when trying to import shaprpy package (python version of shapr package for R). Anyone has experience and can help me?
I have succesfully installed the shapr package in R and run the example code given in the Github repo (https://github.com/NorskRegnesentral/shapr). I want to use the package in Python, because that is where I built my model. However, when I try to import the shaprpy version (python wrapper of shapr package) in a local Jupyter notebook my kernel always dies. Has anyone succesfully run this package in python or had similar problems and knows how to solve this?
I tried installing the package as explained on the Github repo. This didn't work. I also tried cloning the repo and succesfully installed the packages. See picture. However when I just try to import it now, my kernel always dies. succesfully installed shaprpy package

That screenshot does not show you successfully installed the package in the environment your kernel is running in. It just shows it somewhere on your machine. Juptyer is very particular. When you run the corresponding import does it work or give you a module not found error? If you can import then it is installed in the correct environment. Whether it installed properly fully is a different question. Can you import most packages successfully?
